# Ionic V2 Ezar Camera take snapshot returns base64 and not storing in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, angular2-forms

I will try some solution but can't store base64 in  array
1. Html Code

```
<ion-content padding id="ezarcontent">
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
   <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="takePhotos()"> 
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
   </button>
</ion-footer>
```

2.Css code

```
#ezarcontent {
 background-color: transparent !important;
 color: white !important;
}
```

3. typescript code

   public storeImg = [];

   takePhotos(){

   this.platform.ready().then(() => {

   ```
   this.saveCameraImg().then(success => {

     this.storeImg.push(success);
    }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
   });
   ```

   });
    }

   saveCameraImg(): Promise{

   ```
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

     var win: any = window;
     var ezar: any = win.ezar;
     var snapshotBtn = document.getElementById("snapshot");
     var revCameraBtn = document.getElementById("revcamera");
     var inclWebView = true;    
     var inclCameraBtns = true; 

     if (inclWebView && !inclCameraBtns) {
         revCameraBtn.classList.add("hide");
         snapshotBtn.classList.add("hide");              
     }
     ezar.snapshot(
       function(base64EncodedImage) {
         resolve(base64EncodedImage);
       },
       function(error) {
         alert("ezar snapshot failed");
       },
       {"saveToPhotoGallery": true,
        "encoding": ezar.ImageEncoding.PNG,
        "includeWebView": false,
        "includeCameraView": true
      }
     ); 
   });
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

your image needs sanitizer module,Add DomSanitizer in your ts file.The code is below

```
 import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, 
 SafeUrl,SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
     constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

 this.storeImg.push(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(<your response>));
```

I am sure it definitely works.